# How to modify vertical\horisontal headers using double click

Tags: python, qt, pyside

In my Gui I would like to be able to edit the vertical\horizontal headers values of my table (QTableView) using a double click with my mouse.

I am using pyside, but *Qt* solutions in C++, that could show me the way to solve my problem are welcome as well.

If it would be better to use something else then QTableView, I am open for new suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147137/how-do-i-implement-the-ability-to-edit-a-qtablewidgets-vertical-and-horizontal

Comment: @user3419537, you are right. I saw this question and I saw as well "things go bad when headers are resized or table is scrolled"... In my Gui the size of my´table is going to be changed...